# Equivalente do express res.download no restify

Tags: node.js, express.js, restify

Gostaria de mandar um arquivo para o navegador fazer download

No express faço assim:

```
app.get('/apk', (req, res) => {
  res.contentType('application/vnd.android.package-archive');
  res.download(path.join(__dirname, 'apk/apkName.apk'), apkName, (err) => {
      console.log("ERRO? ", err);
      res.send("ERRO! ", err);
  });
});
```

Como seria no restify?

Comment: Creio quen não exista um método equivalente, talvez seja necessario vc mesmo criar uma funcao que leia o arquivo e faca o _stream_ para o front.

Comment: Tentei fazer uma função, mas não tinha conseguido... Mas agora consegui. vou responder

Answer (score 1):

Achei a solução. seria essa:

```
server.get(`/download`, (req, res) => {
  const path = `${process.cwd()}/apk/apkName.apk`;
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.android.package-archive');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=apk/apkName.apk`);

  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
  readStream.pipe(res);
  return res;
});
```